# how to pull down to refresh entire page ASP.NET MVC when browsing with mobile?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devextreme

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC application which require user to pull down to refresh when browsing the website using mobile phone. How can I do that? I don't even know how the machine recognise the gesture of pulling down to the top and intend to refresh, any suggestion?

Comment: That's a standard gesture on Android apps, at least, so I suspect the answer is you don't do anything; the browser translates pulling down to page reload for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many **Pull-To-Refresh plugins**, here to list some of:

- https://github.com/apeatling/web-pull-to-refresh
- https://www.formget.com/jquery-pull-to-refresh-plugins/

However, if you prefer to handle swipe detection yourself without using plugins, you can do so by taking `touchstart`,`touchend`,`mouseup`,`mousedown` events into account. This thread provides you with good insights : [How to detect Pull to refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190436/how-to-detect-pull-to-refresh)