# How to make the listeners always work even when I pull up or down the screen on mobile phones?

Tags: javascript, mobile, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a little library to carry out psychological experiments. You can try it live [here](http://178.62.83.15/test-so/test.html) and try the code in the following snippet.

```js
var selfConcept = (function() {
  //privates    
  var activeListenerStepNames = [];
  var accuracyFeedbackDuration = 400;
  var blankInterval = 1500;
  var clickListenerHandler = function(e) {
    buttonTouched = '';

    switch (e.target.id) {
      case 'd-button':
        buttonTouched = 'D';
        break;
      case 'k-button':
        buttonTouched = 'K';
        break;
    }

    e.data = buttonTouched;

    window.performance.mark(markName);
    window.performance.measure(measureId, generateMarkName('start'), markName);

    responseTimes.push({
      'stepId': currentStep,
      'stimulus': steps[currentStep]['stimulus'],
      'responseTime': window.performance.getEntriesByName(measureId)[0]["duration"],
      'key': e.data
    });

    //fix for Android
    document.getElementById("hidden-input").value = '';

    drawSetting();
    nextStep();
  };
  var currentStep = 0;
  var fixationCrossDuration = 1000;
  var frameId;
  var keyListenerHandler = function(e) {

    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == 'D' || String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == 'K') {
      window.performance.mark(markName);
      window.performance.measure(measureId, generateMarkName('start'), markName);

      responseTimes.push({
        'stepId': currentStep,
        'stimulus': steps[currentStep]['stimulus'],
        'responseTime': window.performance.getEntriesByName(measureId)[0]["duration"],
        'key': String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode),
      });

      isAccuracyFeedbackDisplayed = false;
      removeListener(window, 'input', markName, keyListenerHandler);

      nextStep();
    }
  };
  var spaceListenerHandler = function(e) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == ' ') {
      e.preventDefault();
      removeListener(document, "keydown", markName, spaceListenerHandler);
      drawSetting();
      nextStep();
    }
  }
  var isAccuracyFeedbackDisplayed = false;
  var measureId;
  var responseTimes = [];
  var steps = [];
  var groupInstruction;

  function addListener(element, event, name, eventFunction) {
    element.addEventListener(event, eventFunction);
    activeListenerStepNames.push(name);

    //console.log(activeListenerStepNames);
  }

  function drawSetting(text, color, background) {
    text = (text === undefined) ? '' : text;
    color = (color === undefined) ? 'black' : color;
    background = (background === undefined) ? 'white' : background;

    workAreaDiv = document.getElementById("work-area");
    workAreaDiv.innerHTML = "";

    div = document.createElement('div');

    div.id = 'stimulus';
    div.style.color = color;
    div.innerHTML = text;
    div.style.fontSize = '280%';

    div.style.class = 'col';

    workAreaDiv.appendChild(div);
  }

  function fixForMobilePhones() {
    $('#work-area-container').removeClass('h-100').addClass('h-75');
    $('#container').append('<div class="row h-25"><div id="d-button" style="background-color: black; color: white; border-right: 1px solid white;" class="col-6 text-center"><h1>NO</h1></div><div id="k-button" style="background-color: black; color: white;" class="col-6 text-center"><h1>YES</h1></div></div>');

    addListener(document.getElementById("d-button"), 'click', markName, clickListenerHandler);
    addListener(document.getElementById("k-button"), 'click', markName, clickListenerHandler);
  }

  function generateMarkName(name) {
    return name + '-' + steps[currentStep]["type"] + '-' + currentStep;
  }

  function isMobile() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
    ) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  function nextStep() {
    var nextStep = currentStep + 1;

    if (nextStep in steps) {
      currentStep = nextStep;
      markName = generateMarkName('start');
      window.performance.mark(markName);
      //console.log("mark - markName:"+markName);
    } else {
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(frameId);
      frameId = undefined;

      alert('end');
    }
  }

  function randomizeSteps() {
    words = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8", "word9", "word10"];
    trials = [];

    index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < words.length; index++) {
      trials.push({
        'id': index,
        'type': 'trial',
        'stimulus': words[index]
      });
    }

    instructions = [

      {
        'type': 'duration',
        'stimulus': '',
        'duration': blankInterval
      },
      {
        'type': 'duration',
        'stimulus': '+',
        'color': 'black',
        'duration': fixationCrossDuration
      },
      {
        'type': 'duration',
        'stimulus': '',
        'duration': blankInterval
      }
    ];

    trials = shuffleArray(trials);

    trialsWithBlankInterval = [];

    for (itemIndex = 1; itemIndex < trials.length; itemIndex++) {
      trialsWithBlankInterval.push(trials[itemIndex]);
      trialsWithBlankInterval.push({
        'type': 'duration',
        'stimulus': '',
        'duration': fixationCrossDuration
      });
    }

    steps = instructions.concat(trialsWithBlankInterval);
  }

  function removeListener(element, event, name, eventFunction) {
    element.removeEventListener(event, eventFunction);
    activeListenerStepNames.splice(activeListenerStepNames.indexOf(name), 1);
  }

  /* function copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array */
  function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }

    return array;
  }

  function startTimer() {
    frameId = requestAnimationFrame(startTimer);
    window.performance.mark('frame');
    measureId = 'measure-' + currentStep;

    // console.log("TYPE:"+steps[currentStep]["type"]);

    if (isMobile() == true && $('#work-area-container').hasClass('h-100')) {
      fixForMobilePhones();
    }

    switch (steps[currentStep]["type"]) {
      case 'instructions':
        document.getElementById("work-area").classList.remove('text-center');
        document.getElementById("work-area").classList.add('text-justify');

        document.getElementById("work-area").innerHTML = steps[currentStep]["html"];

        if (activeListenerStepNames.indexOf(markName) == -1) {
          addListener(document, 'keydown', markName, spaceListenerHandler);
        }

        break;

      case 'duration':
        document.getElementById("work-area").classList.remove('text-justify');
        document.getElementById("work-area").classList.add('text-center');
        drawSetting(steps[currentStep]["stimulus"]);

        window.performance.measure(measureId, generateMarkName('start'), 'frame');
        performanceEntries = window.performance.getEntriesByName(measureId);

        var max = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < performanceEntries.length; i++) {
          if (parseInt(performanceEntries[i]["duration"]) > max)
            max = performanceEntries[i]["duration"];
        }

        if (max >= steps[currentStep]["duration"]) {
          //console.log('step: ' + currentStep);
          //console.log(performanceEntries[performanceEntries.length - 1]["duration"]);
          nextStep();
        }

        break;

      case 'trial':
        document.getElementById("work-area").classList.remove('text-justify');
        document.getElementById("work-area").classList.add('text-center');
        drawSetting(steps[currentStep]["stimulus"], steps[currentStep]["color"], steps[currentStep]["background"]);

        markName = generateMarkName('response');

        if (activeListenerStepNames.indexOf(markName) == -1) {
          //console.log(activeListenerStepNames);
          addListener(document, 'keydown', markName, keyListenerHandler);
        }

        break;
    }
  }

  //public
  return {
    init: function() {
      randomizeSteps();

      markName = generateMarkName('start');
      window.performance.mark(markName);
      console.log("INIT");
      startTimer();
    }
  }
})();

selfConcept.init();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

input.transparent {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.text-overflow {
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.likert .row>.col,
.likert .row>[class^="col-"] {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">

  <div id="work-area-container" class="row h-100 text-overflow">
    <div class="col my-auto">
      <div id="work-area" class="w-100 mx-auto text-justify"></div>
      <input id="hidden-input" class="transparent" type="text" readonly="readonly">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Users has to categorize stimuli appeared in the middle of the screen according to two or more options (in the example: "NO" and "YES"). I have to measure in milliseconds the latency from the the moment when the stimulus appears and the keydown on the keyboard (or tap on mobile phones) of the user.

In order to achieve this goal, I used the Web APIs and in particular the [Performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance) object. Moreover, I used Bootstrap4 to make it responsive. Everything is working fine with browsers on desktop or laptop computers: users can respond to the stimulus using the keys D (meaning "NO") and K ("YES").

The problem for which I ask you for help occurs only on mobile phones where the answer mode is based on two visible buttons: "NO" and "YES". I noticed that when I unintentionally I swipe up or down the screen (especially doing it more than once) the listeners no longer work. It's like the window loses the focus and so I have to tap twice on the buttons to make them work (I suppose the first time to gain again the focus, the second time to trigger to events) ruining the measurement of latency times.

I tried to fix this problem in the following way but it doesn't work:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', this.touchstart);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.touchmove);

function touchstart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

function touchmove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

EDIT:
I tried also the following fixes inspired to the [TheMindVirus's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56501941/1148260)

```
var lastScrollPosition = 0;
window.onscroll = function(event)
{
    if((document.body.scrollTop >= 0) && (lastScrollPosition < 0))
    {
        // first try
        window.focus();

        // second try after having assigned tabindex='1' to the div "work-area-container"
       $('#work-area-container').focus();
    }
    
    lastScrollPosition = document.body.scrollTop;
}
```

How I can fix the problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please add that code that works on desktop and laptop. The best way would be to wrap it in an runnable [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) so that everybody can test it on desktop and mobile.

Comment: Done. But the snippet works correctly also from mobile phones. So please see the problem live from your mobile here: http://178.62.83.15/test-so/test.html

Comment: In the snippet and in the linked test site only a word appears but no buttons. The hidden input can be found with the developer tools...

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. As I wrote in the post, on desktop or laptop computers  users can respond to the stimulus using the keys D (meaning "NO") and K ("YES"). The buttons appears only in the mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

Your event listeners and handlers in self-concept.js look fine but the two from your code snippet are wrong. There have to be ordinary function calls:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstart);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmove);
```

You can see the error in the browser console with filename and line number:

```
test.html:51
[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.
```

Which means 'this' is not working here...

I tested your testpage with:

**Galaxy S4 (Android 5):**

- opera mini (works)
- firefox (works)
- chrome (white screen)
- samsung browser (white screen)

**Galaxy S7 (Android 7):**

- firefox (works)
- chrome (works)
- samsung browser (works)

**iPhone 4s (IOS 9.3.5)**

- safari (white screen)

I think it is likely that the problem is not your code but your phone or browser...

Comment: I thank you for the suggestion and I fixed the error but the problem is still there. If I pull up or down the screen (making bouncing the window) the listeners sometimes no longer work and I have to tap twice on a button to answer.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to give the event to the function call ('e') – i fixed it in the answer now. By the way, i tested your site in 4 mobile browsers. In two it worked in any case (changing screen orientation, swiping, zooming) and in the other two i got in any case a white screen...

Comment: Fixed the typo but the problem persists. Could you please list the browsers in which it works or doesn't work?

Comment: Oh, this is an embarrassing situation: just the function reference is necessary and the event is given automatically to it (see the updated answer) – i should have tested it (what i did now) – sorry again...

Comment: No worries. I thank you for your time. Unfortunately the listeners still no longer work when I swipe from the top (or the bottom) of the screen two times or more.

Comment: tested with galaxy S4 (android 5): works: opera mini, firefox; white screen: chrome, samsung browser...

Comment: I updated my answer with my tested devices. What mobile and browser do you use?